# Absolute positioning by reference x,y in FPDF (php)

Tags: fpdf

Is there a way to absolutely position items in FPDF?

SetY() uses relative positioning...
If I wish to write at [100,100] and then go back to position [20,20] on the page...

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: please provide your code, so the others can exactly pointed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SetY() method which allows you to set position at an absolute location in the page, starting from the top or the bottom. For example, SetY(20) or SetY(-20) to start from the bottom of the page.